# How to set default port for .NET Selenium?

Tags: .net, selenium

I use Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver nuget package for selenium. Is it possible to set default port for webdriver instead of using random ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.Port = 40000;
service.Start();
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
```